# load option select from server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to update my option select menu when the button is clicked.
I can make this work by using `$(#id).click(function(){});` but I also have another function that needs to be called when a option is selected from the menu. The code listed below will not work because it clears my select menu out. I believe this is because the click event is called twice, once on the 1st click and 2nd after the change occurs.

What can I do in order to load the select menu in a way I can use both events. Perhaps I am not going about this the proper way, I am still really new to ajax and jquery.

Example of my code:

MyMarkup:

```
<div class="siteId">   Select Site:<select id="site" name="site" 
style="width: 60px"></select></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
getSiteId: function(){  // fill the option select menu

      $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "?do=getsiteid",
              dataType: "json",
              async: true,

              success: function(jsonObj) {

                     var listItems= "";                        
                     listItems+= "<option value='empty'></option>";         // fill first entry with a blank value

                       for (var i in jsonObj){

                               listItems+= '<option value=' + jsonObj[i].siteId + '>' + jsonObj[i].siteId + '</option>';
               }
              $("#site").html(listItems);
              }
       }); 
},
```

My events:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.siteId').click(function(){
    Freight.getSiteId();
  });




  $('#site').change(function(){//event to load table based on user selection from menu

var siteId = $("#site").attr('value');
nEditing = null;
if(siteId != "empty"){
    $("#message").hide();  // hide message
    $("#new").show();      // show button
    $('#wrapper').empty(); // 
    $('#wrapper').replaceWith(Freight.tbl);

    Freight.displayData(siteId);

 oTable = $('#grid').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [ 
        /* Dest */   null,
        /* Port Id */  {"bSearchable": false,
                         "bVisible":    false},
                    /* woodType */ {"bSearchable": false,
                         "bVisible":    false},
        /* Cont Rate */ null,
        /* Edit */  null
    ]} );
}
    else{
    $("#wrapper").empty();
     $("#message").show();  // hide message
    $("#new").hide();      // show button

  } 
}); // end  



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the .click handler is on your .siteId div it is getting called when you click anything inside your div including the SELECT menu. So the .change event for your SELECT is also firing the .click event for the div. I would put a span around the "Select Site" text and put your click event on the span.

Comment: But wouldn't that just make the text clickable and not the combo box?

Comment: That is correct. Do you want the combo box clickable so that it fires the logic to get the options? If so then it seems that you need some logic to decide whether to grab the options or not. Do you only need to fetch the options the first time or any time they click?

Comment: 1. When the option menu is clicked on, it should update all of the options based on the return from the server.

2. The drop option menu also allows a change event to be triggered when an option is selected from the menu.

Comment: So you want the options to be refreshed every time the dropdown is clicked?